# How to make minimap reappear in Farming Sim 2019 on PS4?

Tags: ps4, farming-simulator-2019

I have accidentally hid my minimap and I have no idea how I hid it. I can't find anything explaining how to turn it back on.  How do I make it reappear?

Comment: In case someone has the PC version and is facing the same issue, just press the 9 key repeatedly to toggle between no map, minimap and full map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should press L1 to pop-up the map again ([source](https://guides.gamepressure.com/farming-simulator-19/guide.asp?ID=47687#NH3_3), under additional functions).

[image]

Comment: It's actually L1+L3, as the image you shared shows. I fixed my map, thank you!